# Extjs 4.2.1 hidden field - how could inputEl.dom be undefined?

Tags: javascript, extjs

As part of my application I've created a form with a `Ext.form.field.Hidden` element.
For some reason the 'dom' member of my inputEl is undefined.  It's causing an Uncaught TypeError at line 86938 of ext-all-debug.js when I try to set the field's value programatically:

```
setRawValue: function(value) {
    var me = this;
    value = Ext.value(me.transformRawValue(value), '');
    me.rawValue = value;


    if (me.inputEl) {
        me.inputEl.dom.value = value; // <--- dom here is undefined
    }
    return value;
},
```

Please understand I'm unable to post a minimal example; this is part of a large application and I cannot reproduce the error starting from scratch.

Can anyone suggest how this might come about, or what I can do to further investigate?

Comment: Either, the field has not yet been rendered, or has already been destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone experiencing this; in my case it was tied to the fact I had given the hidden field an `id` attribute, and then some other code in the application had (by design) created more than one instance of the `Form` it was in.  Therefore the id was no longer a unique identifier.  Ext (understandably) seems to dislike this.